# Xlabel fontsize don't change in plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot some data in different plots, and I'm able to do it, but, the labelsize from the x axis don't change in the first plot, but it does in the second one. This is what I'm doing:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta as rd
from calendar import monthrange

fin_mes = date.today() - rd(days=1)
# Start ploting data A
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
# Retrieve dates
mes = fin_mes.strftime("%B")
anio = fin_mes.strftime("%Y")
# Set title
plt.suptitle(f"Data {mes} - {anio}")
# List of days of the last month
num_days = range(1, int(monthrange(fin_mes.day, fin_mes.month)[1]) + 1)
print(num_days)
# Set name from x label
ax.set_xlabel('Dates')
# Set name from y label
ax.set_ylabel('Data')
# Set name from the plot to save
name_a = f"DataA-{mes}-{anio}.png"
plt.title("My Data")
plt.xlim(0, num_days[-1])
plt.ylim((min(num_days)),
         (max(num_days)))
plt.xticks(num_days)
# Setting the size to the label
plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=5)
plt.grid(True)
dataa_plot, = plt.plot(num_days, num_days, label="DATA A")
plt.legend(handles=[dataa_plot])
plt.show()
fig.savefig(name_a)


# Start ploting data B
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
# Retrieve dates
mes = fin_mes.strftime("%B")
anio = fin_mes.strftime("%Y")
# Set title
plt.suptitle(f"Data {mes} - {anio}")
# List of days of the last month
num_days = range(1, int(monthrange(fin_mes.day, fin_mes.month)[1]) + 1)
print(num_days)
# Set name from x label
ax.set_xlabel('Dates')
# Set name from y label
ax.set_ylabel('Data')
# Set name from the plot to save
name_b = f"DataB-{mes}-{anio}.png"
plt.title("My Data B")
plt.xlim(0, num_days[-1])
plt.ylim((min(num_days)),
         (max(num_days)))
plt.xticks(num_days)
# Setting the size to the label
plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=5)
plt.grid(True)
datab_plot, = plt.plot(num_days, num_days, label="DATA B")
plt.legend(handles=[datab_plot])
plt.show()
fig.savefig(name_b)
```

With that I get this plots:

[image: Plot from Data A]

[image]

And plot b has the font size changed, but not plot A. I don't know why this is happening. Hope someone can help me, thanks.

PD: I'm using python 3.8.10 in Lubuntu x64 with matplotlib=3.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the label size **before** using it in setting the ticks, i.e. `plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=5)` must come before `plt.xticks(num_days)` to take effect (the safest way is to move it to the very beginning of the plotting).

As an (easier) alternative you can set the font size directly in `xticks` without changing the rc parameters:

```
plt.xticks(num_days, fontsize=5)
```